# Plugin install error: Installation failed: The package could not be installed

Tags: plugins, installation

An issue with a plugin install via the Add Plugin screen. Error message returned:

Installation failed: The package could not be installed.

This is my plugin, which I have revised. The WP site is hosted on Bluehost; WP version 4.7. I have done the following:

- rebuilt the zip file from scratch (not update)
- ensured that the plugin header is formatted correctly
- ensured that the Readme is formatted correctly (validated it with the Readme Validstor)
- installed the plugin successfully via the Upload, from the same file that Subversion uploaded
- uploaded the zip file and supporting folders to a new Trunk folder matching the version number
- verified that the URL shown via Repobrowser, Copy URL to clipboard is the proper URL for the plugin (matches the plugin name)
- wandered through the googles trying to find similar problem/solutions, to no avail
- looked at the error_log files on the WP site to see relevant errors (there are none related to the install date/time)
- tried the same plugin on other WP sites I own, same error
- looked at similar problems here, to no avail
- have installed other plugins on that (and other) sites just fine without error
- if installed manually (via upload), the plugin works properly/without error

So, am quite puzzled as to what I need to look at to fix the problem. What am I missing?

Comment: Does it work for other plugins?

Comment: The problem plugin does not install on other sites. Other plugins install properly. (See next to last item.)

Manual install of plugin downloaded from plugin repository works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The install problem appears to be an error in how I put files in my Subversion repository. If the files are not in the right place, then the WP plugin install doesn't find them.

My current understanding is that the files belong here

- trunk  - the zip and extracted current versions
- tag    - create a subfolder here for the version number, place zip
  and extracted of current version in same-numbered version folder
- (root) - the current zip and extracted files

Once I put the files in the proper place, the plugin would install via the Add Plugin screen.